# selenium webdriver sleep error in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm a bit confused about this error I'm receiving for a scraping function I wrote in python. I've called the function before and not received this error.

```
content = [link.get_attribute('textContent') for link in wait(browser, 
10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, 
'//ul[@class="twin_set_list"]//a')))]
TypeError: sleep() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
def ct_content(url):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get(url)
    content = [link.get_attribute('textContent') for link in wait(browser, 
    10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, 
    '//ul[@class="twin_set_list"]//a')))]
    dates = [link.get_attribute('textContent') for link in wait(browser, 
    10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, 
    '//p[@class="ellipsis"]//a')))]
    if(len(dates)>4):
        content.append(dates[3])
    else:
        content.append("NO_DW")
    browser.quit()
    return content
```

In this instance the url is: http://www.cellartracker.com/wine.asp?iWine=23683

Any help/insight would be very useful! Thanks

Comment: Show how your `wait()` looks like

Comment: do you mean you want me to `print(wait(browser,10))`

Comment: No. I meant the definition, but I guess it's `from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait `, right?

Comment: yup - you gave it to me

Comment: Hmm...this is weird. Actually there is a `sleep()` in `wait()` definition- the third parameter `poll_frequency` is a value that passed into `sleep()`, but even if to try `wait(driver=browser, timeout=10, poll_frequency=(1, 2))` no type error raised. Also I cannot reproduce the issue with your code. You can try to explicitly set `poll_frequency` value to avoid exception

Comment: I tried defining `poll_frequency = (1,2)` and then passing poll_frequency into both wait calls, but the error now states that sleep has been passed 3 arguments as opposed to the only 1 that it needs. it's as though all arguments that I give to wait are going straight into sleep function call

Comment: poll_frequency has also already been defined in the documentation as `POLL_FREQUENCY = 0.5`

Comment: yep, this is the value that passed to `time.sleep()` by default

Comment: I remember earlier you mentioned that my xpath call could be done without waits as the site was already loaded and didn't need to wait to be changed, can you remind as to how I can change this to no longer include wait with the same URL

Comment: Yes, all required data already present in initial source code. You can try `content = [link.get_attribute('textContent') for link in browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, 
'//ul[@class="twin_set_list"]//a')]`

Comment: ok it seems to work now, thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151001/discussion-between-user7910719-and-andersson).